# display URL in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to display the URL link , however its not showing up, pls. suggest what correction is required here's the code in my XML file

```
<Grains>
   <grain>
      <link url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice" />
   </grain>
</Grain>
```

In XSL File

```
<xsl:template match="Grains/grain/link">
     <xsl:text> details of main ingredient</xsl:text>
     <xsl value-of select="@url"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be: `<xsl:value-of select="@url"/>`

Input XML:

```
<Grains>
   <grain>
      <link url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice" />
   </grain>
</Grains>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Grains/grain/link">
    <xsl:text> details of main ingredient</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```